# Thunderbird update in 16.04 LTS - locales and lightning

Tags: 16.04, updates, thunderbird, calendar

I am running 16.04 LTS and TB 52.5.0

While running a dist-upgrade, the process asks for a removal of some of my TB-locales. I refused and tried a dry-run install of TB in order to see what is going on. Here is the command and the output:

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run install thunderbird

Remv thunderbird-gnome-support [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv thunderbird-locale-en-us [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv thunderbird-locale-en-gb [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv thunderbird-locale-en [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv thunderbird-locale-fr [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv thunderbird-locale-pt [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv xul-ext-gdata-provider [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Remv xul-ext-lightning [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
Inst thunderbird [1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1] (1:52.5.2-1~deb7u1 Debian-Security:7.0/oldoldstable [amd64])
Inst lightning (1:52.5.2-1~deb7u1 Debian-Security:7.0/oldoldstable [amd64])
Conf thunderbird (1:52.5.2-1~deb7u1 Debian-Security:7.0/oldoldstable [amd64])
Conf lightning (1:52.5.2-1~deb7u1 Debian-Security:7.0/oldoldstable [amd64])
```

I don't want my locales to be removed. But I can probably install them afterwards.
But more important, in TB I am running Lightning as a plugin along with the "Provider for Google Calendar" pluging, and I fear that this update will mess up my access to google calendar which would be a huge problem to me. My machine is a production machine and I can not take the risk to loose the R/W access to the Google Calendar (GC).

So my question is two fold : is this behaviour the expected behaviour for the TB update ?
Can someone that experienced a similar situation and did the actual update tell me if the new version of TB still allows for GC R/W access ?

Thank you for your help

LT